# AbstractMethodError for getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I get an exception like below SO question:

[SpringPersistenceUnitInfo :: AbstractMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034545/springpersistenceunitinfo-abstractmethoderror)

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode

My dependencies are in the screenshot, i tried almost all the advices, result is same exception:

[image]

After adding dependencies in answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely missing these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i edited question with screenshot of last view of pom. Error is existing, Thanks.

Comment: there was a conflict, also i had had spring 2.5.6 with spring orm 4.0.4, i deleted pure spring 2.5.6 now the error is gone. Thanks