# How solve Servlet Context Error into Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to develop a new Spring web app, but I have a problem with configuration..

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/jpa-tx-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 25 more
```

This is my `jpa-tx-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.domain"/>

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_H</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">ACTION_TYPE</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy">org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp">True</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS</prop>               
                <prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="my.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAwareBean" />

    <bean id="auditorAwareBean" class="it.cpmapave.ped.auditor.AuditorAwareBean"/>

</beans>
```

I think it is correct..

How can I solve it?

**EDIT**
Add a piece of my pom, maybe can help to understand why.

These are my dependency's version:

```
<jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
<jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
<servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>

<!-- Spring -->
<org.springframework-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<org.springsecurity-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
<spring-data-jpa.version>1.7.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>

<!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
<hibernate.version>5.0.0.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate.validator.version>5.0.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>

<!-- Jackson -->
<jackson.version>2.2.2</jackson.version>

<!-- QueryDSL -->
<querydsl.version>3.3.2</querydsl.version>
```

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: @AtulRai Yes! I add it :)

Comment: "java.lang.AbstractMethodError at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl". Can't get clearer than that. Incorrect Hibernate jars/dependencies

Comment: i think it's a library versions mismatch see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034545/springpersistenceunitinfo-abstractmethoderror) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your pom version:

```
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springsecurity-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.8.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>

    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.0.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
```

I don't have understand why to downgrade the version of hibernate it run.. but I had the same problem, and with this method I had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be jar version issue
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html

can you check you spring version dependency are correct?

Comment: I edited my question and I added the version about some dependency into my pom...

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I've experienced this error only when I tried to create a new **Spring Legacy Project**, with a **SpringMVCproject template**, and only if I tried to do it in a machine GNU-Linux inside.
Over Windows10 seems it works as template rules.

My configuration is Linux Ubuntu 16 + Elipse Photon 4.8.0 + Spring Tools 3.9.6.

Two fixes were necessary in my own case:

In the **pom.xml** file, inside the tag `<org.springframework-version>`, the template writes 3.1.1.RELEASE, wich seems is not the correct release, I've changed it in this way:

```
<org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

The second fix I've done was in the **web.xml** file: Inside of the `<servlet-name>` tags, the template writes `appServlet`, and you'll need this fix:

```
<servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
```

Save both files, right click on the project name, choose Maven>Update Project, and then Run it in the server.

I hope it may be useful, before you got crazy.

----Annexe I ------
This reference in [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-dependency-management) may help to understand this issue.

---- Annexe II ----
I've searched before by:

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start

org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.

org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]